# Can I get the extent that contains all the features satisfying a WFS GetFeature request from GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, getfeature

With `GeoServer 2.16.2`, I use a `WFS GetFeature` request to query features from multiple layers, each having different CQL filters. Something like:

```
<URL>/wfs?service=WFS
&version=2.0.0
&request=GetFeature
&typeNames=workspace:layer1,workspace:layer2,workspace:layer3,...
&outputFormat=application/json
&cql_filter=filter1;filter2;filter3,...
```

I have no problem with getting the feature count, processing the result and using it in my client application.

What I'd like to do is to **get the extent that fits all the features returned by this request**.

I could add all the features to my client (`OpenLayers 5.3.0`) and get the extent but there are a lot of features, so I don't add all of them to the map, only those currently within the map view in the browser. Still, in some cases I'd like to know the extent that fits all features.

What I tried is processing the result of the `WFS GetFeature` request in my backend, loop through all coordinates of all geometries and find the extent this way. It works, but it seems to be very inefficient to me, and in case of ten thousands of features it can be slow.

I searched for a solution but could not find anything related. So my question is: **is it possible to get the extent described above without having to loop through all coordinates or adding all the features to a map client**?

Comment: I think you will need to loop through all the features somewhere to get the extent - maybe a WPS call would help?

Comment: @IanTurton Thanks for the tip, I will check this possibility out. It could be quicker than doing the same in my backend, but still, it means another request. I thought that since GeoServer does this loop anyway to answer my WFS request, there is a built-in functionality.

Comment: The spec requires it as the first element but geoserver is streaming the response so doesn't know what is coming at that point.

Comment: @IanTurton I understand, thanks for the explanation.